# Specify number of samples in a segment for Short-time Fourier Transform using SciPy stft function

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, fft, data-processing

I wanted to perform Short-time Fourier Transform on my data with a specific sample length for each segment. I wanted to use the SciPy function `stft` from the signal submodule. However, when I create an audio array of length `10e5` the following way:

```
fs = 10e3 # Sampling frequency
N = 1e5 # Number of samples
time = np.arange(N) / fs
x = 500*np.cos(time) # Some random audio wave
# x.shape gives (100000,)
```

And apply the SciPy `stft` function with `nperseg=1000`, I do not get a 100 segments as expected. Instead, the shape of the output is:

```
f, t, Zxx = signal.stft(x, fs, nperseg=1000)
print(Zxx.shape) # -> (501, 201)
```

Where if I understand the docs correctly 501 is the number of "frequency baskets" and 20001 is the number of different time segments, which I was originally intending to be N/nperseg or 10e5 / 1000 = 100. I do see that the function has some parameters to specify padding and overlap, but in the case when `N` is divisible by `nperseg`, what does it exactly do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I run your code snippet:

```
In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]: import scipy.signal as signal

In [3]: fs = 10e3 # Sampling frequency
   ...: N = 1e5 # Number of samples
   ...: time = np.arange(N) / fs
   ...: x = 500*np.cos(time) # Some random audio wave
   ...:

In [4]: f, t, Zxx = signal.stft(x, fs, nperseg=1000)
   ...: print(Zxx.shape) # -> (501, 20001)
   ...:
(501, 201)
```

I see that the output of `Zxx` is 501 by 201.

501 is, as you say, the number of frequency bins (1000 temporal bins per segment, after real-only FFT, becomes 501 frequency bins; if you want full complex FFT, you can pass in `return_onesided=False`).

The 201 is because of the combination of `nperseg` and `noverlap`. The [docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.stft.html) say that `noverlap` is “Number of points to overlap between segments. If `None`, `noverlap = nperseg // 2`.” So STFT is *not* making 1e5/1e3=1e2 “segments”, it’s overlapping 1e3-long segments by 500 samples (half-a-segment), so you end up with a little more than 200 *overlapped* segments.

To get what you want, say `noverlap=0`:

```
In [7]: f, t, Zxx = signal.stft(x, fs, nperseg=1000, noverlap=0)

In [8]: Zxx.shape
Out[8]: (501, 101)
```

I am not really sure why it returns 101 segments instead of 100…

Answer (score 0):

The signal.stft got a default window overlap of 50% which roughly doubles the number of the segments. 
Searching "stft overlap" in google will help you to learn more about this overlapping.